# How to remove all instances of double quotes from a CSV file?

Tags: text-processing, csv, text

I've got a huge (about half a GiB, impossible to use a usual text editor on) CSV file with fields enclosed in double quotes like `"abc","def"` but need a file without quotes (I am sure this is not going to break the file consistency - a comma is never used inside the values in it).

How to remove all the quotes (without introducing spaces on their places)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`tr` can do that:

```
tr -d \" < infile > outfile
```

You could also use `sed`:

```
sed 's/"//g' < infile > outfile
```

Comment: Why did you removed `< infile > outfile`? IMHO it was more informative.

Comment: @Ivan I thought it was probably implicit on second thought.

Comment: Only when for experienced command line users. Even though I a have used `<` before a couple of times (to import SQL scripts into MySQL and SQLite) It would be immediately obvious for me that I should use `<` in this case. I think it would be better to return the full command line example back for further reference of those who may need it.

Comment: @Ivan and @Chris, I've reverted it back (pending review) to include `< infile > outfile`, hope that's OK.

Comment: Thanks, @donothingsuccessfully. I've totally mistyped the previous comment, that's a pity I can't edit it %-]

Answer (score 7):

Another version of **sed** command:

```
sed -i s/\"//g file.txt
```

- `sed` **s**tream **ed**itor

  - `-i` **i**n-place (edit file in place)
  - `s` the **s**ubstitute command
  - `/replacement_from_reg_exp/replacement_to_text/` statement
  - `\"` quotes preceded by backslash (*replacement_from_reg_exp*)
  - empty string between slash delemiters (*replacement_to_text*)
  - `g` **g**lobal (for replace all occurrence in line)
- `file.txt` the file name

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the double quotes if you read the data using a CSV-aware library.  The rest of this answer shows how you may remove the unneeded double quotes from a generic CSV file, for the case where you rely on a more simplistic approach to parsing the data later.

[Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) would be able to read the CSV data and output it again using just

```bash
mlr --csv cat file
```

(Use with `-I` to do "in-place" editing.)

Miller would by default only quote fields that require quoting, e.g. fields containing embedded commas, quotes, or newlines.

In the same fashion, `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would similarly only by default quote fields that actually require quoting:

```bash
csvformat file
```

The `csvformat` utility can't do "in-place" editing, so you would need to redirect the output to a new name.